# Convert field to EditText

Tags: android

Hi I'm sure this is simple and its just eluding me :-)

i am writing a simple helper class to be able to check the values provided in a Field array the fields are saying they are EditText Widgets which is correct, what i want to do is be able to access the input value which was entered into the EditText Field, please help?

```
Field[] fields = clazz.getFields();

    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Required.class)) {
            Log.d(TestClass.class.getName(), field.toString());
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

UPDATE to QUESTION full code

```
package com.mobiqube.annotations;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditTextValidator {

public EditTextValidator() {
}

public Boolean validate(Class clazz) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
    Boolean isValid = true;
    Field[] fields = clazz.getFields();

    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Required.class)) {
            Log.d(EditTextValidator.class.getName(), field.toString());
            if(field instanceof EditText){      
                EditText editText = (EditText)field ;
                String txt=editText.getText().toString();
                Log.d(EditTextValidator.class.getName(), txt);
            }

        }
    }

    return isValid;
}

public String getMessage(){
    String returnStr = "";
    return returnStr;
}
```

}

errors now being

```
if(field instanceof EditText){ //
```

and
    EditText editText = (EditText)field ;

Comment: you need the object that is an instance of your clazz class, and you need to use field.get(instance). To get the class represented by the field, use field.getType()

Comment: errmm so would i be right in the following EditText editText = (EditText) field.get(field.getType());

Comment: not quite. you need an instance of type clazz. Can you post a little more code regarding the clazz object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an object of type clazz :

```
MyClass object = <something>

// clazz represent the class of this object
Class<?> clazz = object.getClass();
// Note that it can also be obtained by MyClass.class

// fields represent the members of MyClass
Field[] fields = clazz.getFields();

for (Field field : fields) {
    // field is a member of MyClass
    // To get the class of this member :
    Class<?> c = field.getType();
    // To get the value of the member in the object: (object is an instance of MyClass)
    Object o = field.get(object);
    // If you want to know if the field represent an EditText or a derived class :
    if (EditText.class.isAssignableFrom(c)) {
        EditText value = (EditText) field.get(object);
    }
}
```

Regarding your question, you need the object that you are trying to validate, as the class itself is not sufficient (unless you are only validating the static fields ?)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
EditText[] fields = clazz.getFields();

for (EditText field : fields) {
   Log.e("result",field.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: did you try this? it doesn't even compile

Comment: I already mentioned, it will work if Field is an array of EditText

Comment: @cghrmauritius Can you please let me know the Object class of Field?

Comment: What is the type of clazz?

Comment: fields, apparently, is an array of Field, which cannot be casted in EditText.

Comment: see my updated answer. I am assuming that clazz.getFields is returning EditText array as said in post

Comment: for (Field field : fields) {
   if   (field.isAnnotationPresent(Required.class)) {
    Log.d(EditTextValidator.class.getName(), field.toString());
    if(field instanceof EditText){      
        EditText editText = (EditText)field ;
        String txt=editText.getText().toString();
    }
    Log.d(EditTextValidator.class.getName(), editText.getText().toString());
   }
  }

Comment: the question is quite explicite `Field[] fields = clazz.getFields();`

Comment: no this doesnt compile the EditText[] fields = clazz.getFields(); says canot convert

Comment: you need to tell me what is clazz.getFields() is returning exactly. Is this your custom method or built in? Besides, what is clazz? you need to tell me the fields present within this class. This is the basic info which is necessary to solve this issue

Comment: clazz is an activity.class and the  Log.d(EditTextValidator.class.getName(), field.toString()); says that each field is an EditText Widget

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Please paste your logcat over here

Comment: ok it doesnt even compile the line if(field instanceof EditText) says 'Incompatible conditional operand types Field and EditText' and the next line EditText editText = (EditText)field says 'Cannot cast from Field to EditText'. HOPE THIS HELPS

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use below code

```
if(field instanceof EditText){      
    EditText editText = (EditText)field ;
    String txt=editText.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: did you try this? it doesn't even compile

Comment: Sorry but i get the following error "Cannot cast from Field to EditText", any ideas please

Answer (score 0):

```
AppCompatActivity activity=(AppCompatActivity)
Field id = R.id.class.getDeclaredField(field.getName());
EditText et= (EditText)activity.findViewById(id.getInt(id));

//or
AppCompatActivity activity=(AppCompatActivity)
EditText et= (EditText)activity.findViewById(id);
```

Comment: provide heading for your answer

Comment: Hello! When answering a question, please include an explanation of your code and how you have solved the problem. This is particularly relevant if you're answering an old post like this one – could you comment on the other answers, why have you found it necessary to add this?

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.